# equivalent option in ffmpeg for ffplay's -infbuff

Tags: video, ffmpeg, udp, multicast

I have a multicast UDP stream that I can watch (with almost no errors) if I use ffplay's infbuf option.

But when I try to encode it via ffmpeg, ffmpeg reports a lot of errors and the resultant video has lots of errors.

I have tried setting the  fifo_size to a super large value  like 655360 and the buf_size  as per  https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#udp. But none of gets rid of the decode errors in ffmpeg.

Is it possible to provide settings to ffmpeg that do something similar to what ffplay's -intbuf does?  I want my video encode to be as error free as video playback via ffplay.

Comment: How coincidental is it that we have the exact same problem? I've attempted to use the fifo_size option for the udp output but am met with a segfault above some arbitrary size.